# import products csv file fails with 'Specified URL key already exists in row(s)' error

Tags: magento2, category, import, products, csv

I have the following error "Specified URL key already exists in row(s): 99, 124, 179, 190, 194, 222, 271, 297, 326, 328, 329, 332".  When I tried to import some 338 simple products with created categories into my local Magento 2.1.8 CE website. But the url_key column in my products csv file is empty.

Comment: I input the specified rows url_key column with its sku to pass the 'Check Data' button.  But when I tried to import the checked csv file, I got the error ' Category "Default Category/Azuregreen Herbs/Herb By The Pound N - Z" has not been created. URL key for specified store already exists. in row(s): 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13'.  but in fact the category for the specified rows has been created.